# XMPP: Registration gives error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

Hi I a using the below code for registration.

After xmppStream has been connected then I call this code inside didNotAuthenticate method:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{

    NSString *jidStr = @"mohit@localhost";
    NSString password = @"mohit";
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidStr];
    [self  xmppStream].myJID =jid;

    if (self.xmppStream.supportsInBandRegistration) {
        if (![self.xmppStream registerWithPassword:password error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Registration error: %@", error);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Registration on progress");
        }
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"Inband registration is not supported");
    }
}
```

in Console it prints the "Registration on progress" but in the below delegate method

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement *)error{
    DDXMLElement *errorXML = [error elementForName:@"error"];
    NSString *errorCode  = [[errorXML attributeForName:@"code"] stringValue];
    NSString *regError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR :- %@",error.description];
    NSLog(@"%@",regError);
}
```

It gives error:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="localhost" type="error"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
<username>mohit</username><password>mohit</password></query><error code="403" type="auth">
<forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

I am using the ejabberd server. Please help me on this.

Comment: Just enable registration in ejabberd configuration file

Comment: Ejabberd configuration problem.

Comment: I don't think so. I have it set to `register [{allow,all}]`

Answer (score 4):

Following steps worked for me

1. Go to your Ejabbered admin home page and login with admin credentials. ("http://YourServerHostName:5280/admin/")
2. Click on "Access Rules" from left side menu.
3. In the textfield at the bottom the page, paste the following access rule and click "Add New".

   **{access, register_from, [{allow, all}]}**

   This should eliminate the 403 forbidden error.
4. After forbidden error is resolved one more error may arrive that is "**Users are not allowed to register accounts so quickly**". For this again copy and paste the following access rule in the same textfield and click "Add New".

   **{access, register, [{all, allow}, {registration_timeout, infinity}]}**

   This should eliminate the above error.

Comment: Great! For me it worked to go to Virtual Host-Nodes-Modules-mod_register and add the access rules you described.